# Strange Shortcut Key behaviour when developing windows forms app in two languages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I recently ran into a rather strange problem: I developed a Windows Forms app (C#) in Visual Studio 2017. The initial implementation was done on a english version (System and Visual Studio). The application features several forms, which can be opened via shortcut key combination (e.g. ctrl + alt + P).

Now, recently I had to continue development on a german system with germen Visual Studio installed. I was quite surprised, that the above mentioned shortcuts lead to a building failure. Only after changing the shortcuts to "Strg + ALt + P" it would work - but only on this system; on a ENG System the build fails, since "Strg" is not recognized.

Why in gods sake does Visual Studio consider the keys depending on the system / version language? It can't be that such things as keys and so on are dependent on the language, no? This would mean, that it is not possible to develop an application which is buildable in more than one language - and with this multilingual teams would not be possible anymore...
What am I missing? I already tried to translate the Shortcuts within the ENG and GER resx file, but this wouldn't solve the problem neither.
Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm stuck here.

Comment: What was the build error?

Comment: Your shortcut are obviously badly implemented. If you use `Keys` it will be the same no matter the system language.

Comment: @Franck then I guess the bad implementation is within visual studio. I got a menu bar in the form and added the shortcuts via properties (click on menu item, go to properties, scroll to "Shortcut", activate checkboxes "Ctrl" and "Alt" and select key "P").

Comment: @MatthewWatson something like "invalid ResX... Value 'Strg' not found..."

Comment: @MatthewWatson that is 'Strg' after switching from german system/version to english, 'Ctrl' after switching from english to german...

Comment: @Tyron78 You must have something broken, The keys are binded to the keyboard language. I do run English, German and French and they are all hooked to Keys and CTRL stays CTRL. My int code is still 131072

Comment: I'm wondering.. When I set a menu shortcut, it is written as C# code in Form1.Designer.cs, which is not a .resx file. In resx files you can store strings, images, icons, media files etc., but not shortcuts as such. So, how exactly do you store a shortcut in resx file?

Comment: Do you actually mean a .settings file instead of .resx file?

Comment: It is a TypeConverter that translates the string you enter in the Properties window to a value that gets embedded in InitializeComponent().  KeysConverter in this case.  Which does use [localized names](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/KeysConverter.cs,68) for these keys.  Localized to your machine, not the user's machine.  I'd guess you use the Language Bar to switch languages, don't do that while editing.

Comment: The language isn't changed (it's "standard"), the shortcut is NOT keyed in but edited via the Properties as described above, the problem is within the resx file which was generated automatically...


  `<data name="MenuItem_InterneParameter.ShortcutKeys" type="System.Windows.Forms.Keys, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>Ctrl+Alt+P</value>
  </data>`


I did NOT switch the language during editing but worked on a totally different machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "feature" of Visual Studio. Known workaround: set all shortcuts in code, instead of in editor.

[MSBuild cannot process resource files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ab50ba0-9be1-49e8-b4f6-7cfd97eccf10/msbuild-cannot-process-resource-files?forum=msbuild)
[Problems with shortcuts (e.g. Ctrl + P) in resx files when using VS2017 an a German Windows](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/29523/problems-with-shortcuts-eg-ctrl-p-in-resx-files-wh.html)
[Is there a way to fix Visual Studio ResX-Keyboard shortcut problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56494428)

Other possible workaround, complex but doable if you use a versioning system, would be to employ some scripts that would maintain `Ctrl` in repository, but convert it to `Strg` on client side, where required.

One thing to note here, this does not happen if you don't use localization. In that case all data is stored in source code. But if you set form's `Localizable` property to true then properties are stored to .resx files. Microsoft knows about the problem from long ago, and will not fix it. Their suggested workaround: use only English Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, we changed to `Localizable` lately since we required the application in german and english (was english only before). However, I just followed your recommendation and implemented all shortcuts within the code.